# exclude empty objects from result set when using .reduce()

Tags: javascript, reduce

The `.reduce()` method is being employed to perform data validation.  Below is a simplified sample of the data in the `preMigration` and `postMigration` objects.  The actual dataset has several more pairs in the "line" and "profile" parts.

Although the math is being performed correctly, the resulting output of the `deepSubtract()` method includes empty objects (`{}`) for "line" and for the indexes within "profile" when the results from both objects match.  For the live version of the data, which is lengthy, this is problematic as the volume of data to review is huge and most of it is empty objects.

Is there a way to modify the logic of `deepSubract()` to exclude empty objects from the final output?  The desired result for the given example is displayed below the code snippet.

```js
const preMigration = {
    "100": {
        "line": {
            "machines": 1,
            "operators": 4
        },
        "profile": [
            {
                "capacity": 0.8,
                "downtimeAllowance": 0.99
            },
            {
                "capacity": 0.95,
                "downtimeAllowance": 0.7
            }
        ]
    },
    "200": {
        "line": {
            "machines": 6,
            "operators": 12
        },
        "profile": [
            {
                "capacity": 0.9,
                "downtimeAllowance": 0.85
            }
        ]
    },
    "300": {
        "line": {
            "machines": 9,
            "operators": 3
        },
        "profile": [
            {
                "capacity": 0.85,
                "downtimeAllowance": 0.71
            },
            {
                "capacity": 0.94,
                "downtimeAllowance": 0.97
            }
        ]
    }
}

const postMigration = {
    "100": {
        "line": {
            "machines": 1,
            "operators": 0
        },
        "profile": [
            {
                "capacity": 0.8,
                "downtimeAllowance": 0.99
            },
            {
                "capacity": 0.95,
                "downtimeAllowance": 0.7
            }
        ]
    },
    "200": {
        "line": {
            "machines": 6,
            "operators": 12
        },
        "profile": [
            {
                "capacity": 0.9,
                "downtimeAllowance": 0.85
            }
        ]
    },
    "300": {
        "line": {
            "machines": 9,
            "operators": 5
        },
        "profile": [
            {
                "capacity": 0.85,
                "downtimeAllowance": 0.71
            },
            {
                "capacity": 0.96,
                "downtimeAllowance": 0.97
            }
        ]
    }
}

this.deepSubtract = (obj1, obj2) => {
    const uniqueKeys = [...new Set([...Object.keys(obj1), ...Object.keys(obj2)])];
    const reduction = uniqueKeys.reduce((acc, key) => {
        if (typeof obj2[key] === 'object') {
            acc[key] = this.deepSubtract(obj1[key], obj2[key]);
        } else {
            if (obj1[key] !== obj2[key]) acc[key] = obj1[key] - obj2[key]
        }
        return acc;
    }, {});
    return reduction;
}

const dataValidation = deepSubtract(postMigration, preMigration);
console.log(JSON.stringify(dataValidation, null, 4));
```

Desired output for this example:

```
{
    "100": {
        "line": {
            "operators": -4
        }
    },
    "300": {
        "line": {
            "operators": 2
        },
        "profile": {
            "1": {
                "capacity": 0.020000000000000018
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're trying to do too much in a single function, and it's illegible. Compare objects in separate functions, it's way easier to understand what you're doing and it'll be way easier to get the right answer.

Comment: Someone posted an answer yesterday that worked, and I marked it as the answer, but today it is gone.  How can that answer be restored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, someone's working answer that was posted yesterday somehow disappeared.  Fortunately, I read it and tried out the code before it vanished.  Below is what I ended up using -

```js
const preMigration = {
    "100": {
        "line": {
            "machines": 1,
            "operators": 4
        },
        "profile": [
            {
                "capacity": 0.8,
                "downtimeAllowance": 0.99
            },
            {
                "capacity": 0.95,
                "downtimeAllowance": 0.7
            }
        ]
    },
    "200": {
        "line": {
            "machines": 6,
            "operators": 12
        },
        "profile": [
            {
                "capacity": 0.9,
                "downtimeAllowance": 0.85
            }
        ]
    },
    "300": {
        "line": {
            "machines": 9,
            "operators": 3
        },
        "profile": [
            {
                "capacity": 0.85,
                "downtimeAllowance": 0.71
            },
            {
                "capacity": 0.94,
                "downtimeAllowance": 0.97
            }
        ]
    }
}

const postMigration = {
    "100": {
        "line": {
            "machines": 1,
            "operators": 0
        },
        "profile": [
            {
                "capacity": 0.8,
                "downtimeAllowance": 0.99
            },
            {
                "capacity": 0.95,
                "downtimeAllowance": 0.7
            }
        ]
    },
    "200": {
        "line": {
            "machines": 6,
            "operators": 12
        },
        "profile": [
            {
                "capacity": 0.9,
                "downtimeAllowance": 0.85
            }
        ]
    },
    "300": {
        "line": {
            "machines": 9,
            "operators": 5
        },
        "profile": [
            {
                "capacity": 0.85,
                "downtimeAllowance": 0.71
            },
            {
                "capacity": 0.96,
                "downtimeAllowance": 0.97
            }
        ]
    }
}

this.deepSubtract = (obj1, obj2) => {
    const uniqueKeys = [...new Set([...Object.keys(obj1), ...Object.keys(obj2)])];
    const reduction = uniqueKeys.reduce((acc, key) => {
        if (typeof obj2[key] === 'object') {
            const subtractedObject = this.deepSubtract(obj1[key], obj2[key]);
            if (Object.keys(subtractedObject).length > 0) acc[key] = subtractedObject;  // add subtractedObject to acc only if it's not empty
        } else {
            if (obj1[key] !== obj2[key]) acc[key] = obj1[key] - obj2[key];
        }
        return acc;
    }, {});
    return reduction;
}

const dataValidation = deepSubtract(postMigration, preMigration);
console.log(JSON.stringify(dataValidation, null, 4));
```